# Java 8 How to check if one number is divided by more than 1 number using Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can i check if one range from numbers is divided by more than one number. For example if it is only 1 divisor this will work , but i don't know what to do when i have an array from numbers :

```
int limitNumber = 10;
int onlyOneDivisor = 2;
String input = "2 3";
int[] nums = Arrays.stream(input.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

//This works fine, but it's divided only by 2

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, limitNumber).filter(n -> (n % onlyOneDivisor == 0))
.forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));
```

Comment: I can't quite figure out what the end goal is.

Comment: The end goal is to print all numbers from 0 to 10 , that are divided by 2 and 3 in this example

Comment: That would mean then it's divided by 6, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter`, filtering by another stream over all the divisors, and using `allMatch` or `anyMatch`, depending on the exact use case:

```
int max = 10;
int[] divisors = {2, 3, 5};

// no divisor
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, max)
        .filter(n -> IntStream.of(divisors).allMatch(d -> n % d != 0))
        .forEach(System.out::println);

// any divisor
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, max)
        .filter(n -> IntStream.of(divisors).anyMatch(d -> n % d == 0))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you want to check whether a number has exactly two divisors (given a list of more than two), you could use an inner `filter` and combine that with `count`:

```
// exactly two divisors
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, max)
        .filter(n -> IntStream.of(divisors).filter(d -> n % d == 0).count() == 2)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note, however, that if you want to find prime numbers, you should probably not use a fixed list of divisors, but determine the divisors from the number under test:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, max)
        .filter(n -> IntStream.range(2, n).allMatch(d -> n % d != 0))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

(Using `n` as the upper bound here is not very efficient; `sqrt(n)` would be enough, and only the odd numbers and two, and many more optimization.)

Answer (score 1):

You could apply one `filter` per divisor.

```
IntStream stream = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, limitNumber);

for (int divisor: divisors) {
    stream = stream.filter(n -> n % divisor == 0);
}

stream.forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));
```

To do it in one go you need to check for divisibility by all factors at once. It's a bit much to write out inline, so I recommend a helper method `isDivisibleByAll` (implementation left as an exercise).

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, limitNumber)
    .filter(n -> isDivisibleByAll(n, divisors))
    .forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));
```

A smarter approach might be to compute the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of the factors, then just check for divisibility by that number.

Comment: For the sake of using streams, the filter could be `...filter(n -> Arrays.stream(divisors).allMatch(d -> (n % d) == 0))`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `allMatch` within `filter`:

```
String input = "2 3";

int[] divisors = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .toArray();

int limitNumber = 10;

IntStream.rangeClosed(0, limitNumber) // maybe 1 and not 0?
    .filter(n -> Arrays.stream(divisors).allMatch(d -> n % d == 0))
    .forEach(System.out::println); // 0 6
```

Here I'm streaming over the `divisors` array within `filter`, to check that *all* divisors actually divide the current number. If this condition is successful, the number remains in the stream and is finally printed.

Answer (score 0):

"Divided by more than 1 number" means it's not *[prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)*, so:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, limitNumber)
  .filter(this::isNotPrime)
  .forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));
```

Then define a method:

```
private boolean isNotPrime(int n) {
    int s = (int)Math.sqrt(n);
    for (int i = 2; i < s; i++)
        if (n % 2 == 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```